# Oracle Pivot SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I would like two ID's to be pivoted into the same row based on matching/like PAIR field values.  Currently the ID's are just listed in a single column and I am ordering by the PAIR field value.

Below is the query that I am currently running.

```
select ID,PAIR
from   Table
where   PAIR in
 (select PAIR from Table  
  where ID  in
   (select ID
   from review
   where rule = 1234456
   and trunc(RECVDDATE) = trunc(sysdate-1) 
   )
 )
order by PAIR;

        ID PAIR
   4173910 1175
   4423979 1175
   4425330 17B5
   4106895 17B5
   4421153 E54E
   3706124 E54E

6 rows selected.
```

I would like this as my desired result.  Basically pivoting the ID based on like/matching PAIR values.

```
     ID(1)   ID(2)
   4173910 4423979
   4425330 4106895
   4421153 3706124
```

Comment: You don't need the value of PAIR in the result? Then: How do you decide which ID to show as ID(1) and which as ID(2)? Also note that column names with parentheses in them are not a good idea; how about ID_1 and ID_2, for example?

Comment: Also: For any given PAIR, do you know for sure you will get at most two different ID's? If not (if for a PAIR you may get three or more ID's), which two ID's do you want to show in the "desired result"?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I could also display PAIR in the result, but its not necessary.

Comment: ID_1 and ID_2 are a better option.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: We will only have 2 ID's for each PAIR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your exact requirement (see my Comments below your question), this may work:

(1) Add `GROUP BY PAIR` right before `ORDER BY PAIR`.

(2) Change the `SELECT` clause to

```
select min(id) as id_1, case when max(id) != min(id) then max(id) end as id_2
```

The `CASE` expression is there in case there is only one `ID` for some `PAIR` values - in that case `ID_2` should not repeat the value from `ID_1`, but should be `NULL` instead. (That's how `PIVOT` would work, anyway.)

Note that this solution doesn't use the `PIVOT` operator; given what you have already, adding aggregation is simpler. `PIVOT` would require making your current query into a subquery and then pivoting in an outer `SELECT` statement.

If you prefer, for brevity you could use `NULLIF(MAX(ID), MIN(ID))` instead of the `CASE` expression; it means exactly the same thing.

Comment: Thats awesome!  Thank you so much.  I went with the case option.

Comment: I have a follow up.  I dont want to post another question.  How would I also return the REVIEW / RECVDDATE value?